# How can I modify an NSButton that I dragged from the library in my code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I dragged a button from the library to the window. I have the button linked to an IBAction in the AppDelegate.h, and now I want to change the title of the button in the AppDelegate.m file, how can I access that button, should I type "self.window....setTitle:" or whatever? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to make IBOutlet?

Comment: I got it! I used to think button can only have IBAction. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `IBOutlet` to the `NSButton`  is `myButton` then use

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"New Title"];
```

or even

```
[_myButton setTitle:@"New Title"]; //If you are using XCode4.4+ as @synthesize will be there creating _myButton.
```

---

As you said you have connected the button to an IBAction then you can simply do :

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{
    sender.title=@"New Title";
}
```

Comment: @AnoopVaidya@MahmoudFayez I see...haha